# How do you move files/folders across volumes with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I try to move a folder with PowerShell

```
move-item  c:\test c:\test2
```

works, but

```
move-item c:\test  \\192.168.1.50\c$\test2
```

does not and tells me

> Move-Item : Source and destination
>   path must have identical roots. Move
>   will not work across volumes.

Answer (score 25):

If `test` is a directory, it won't work, as the [documentation for `Move-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx) states:

> `Move-Item` will move files between drives that are supported by the same provider, but it will move directories only within the same drive.

You can use `Copy-Item` followed by a `Remove-Item` in that case:

```
try {
  Copy-Item -Recurse C:\test \\192.168.1.50\c$\test2 -ErrorAction Stop
  Remove-Item -Recurse c:\test
} catch {}
```

Another option, if you don't rely on PSDrives, would be to simply use xcopy or robocopy.

Comment: And they'll probably want to use `-recurse` on those.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. Didn't think of that `cpi` doesn't bother copying contents of directories. I rarely do filesystem stuff with PS.

Comment: if you use CI+RI you have to make sure that items won't be deleted in case CI fails (unreachable destination for example). Use '-ErrorAction Stop' with combination of Try/catch directives

Comment: Ilyax: He's referring to the combination of `Copy-Item` and `Remove-Item`.

Comment: I can handle this process with 10 lines of C#, but I want to make it up to powershell how this can be difficult to ,folders and files in the folder cant not copy

Answer (score 4):

This needs to be tightened up and should probably be made into a function but it works.

```
$source = "<UNC Path>"
$destination = "<UNC Path>"

if (test-path $destination -PathType Container) 
{
  foreach ( $srcObj in (get-childitem $source )) 
  { 
    $srcObjPath = "$($srcObj.fullname)"
    $destObjPath = "$($destination)\$($srcObj.name)" 
    If((Test-Path -LiteralPath $destination)) 
     {
       copy-item $srcObjPath $destination -recurse
       if ( (Test-Path -Path $destObjPath ) -eq $true)
       {
        if ( (compare-object (gci $srcObjPath -recurse) (gci $destObjPath -recurse)) -eq $null)
        {
         write-output "Compare is good. Remove $($srcObjPath)"
         remove-item $srcObjPath -recurse
        }
        else
        {
          write-output "Compare is bad. Remove $($destObjPath)"
          remove-item $destObjPath -recurse
         }
       }
       else 
       { 
        write-output "$($destination) path is bad" 
       }
     }
  else
  {
    write-output "bad destinaton: $($destination)"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I found out that on destination folder, user permissions were limited. I changed full permissions on source and destination drive and move went smoothly. No identical roots error message on move-item command.