# Move list of empty folders from one volume to another with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell 2.0 on a Windows SBS 2008 machine with the latest service packs. I have a two line script that finds all empty folders in a directory:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem E:\File_Server -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$a | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | [what now?!]
```

The second line finds all folders that are empty, however I'm stumped on the last pipe. Here's what I've tried so far (keep in mind that the following were tried after the second pipe in the second line above):

`$_.move(F:\path)` Yes, I tried that. Yes, I'm a PowerShell noob. Of course, I received the error "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

`move-item -destination F:\Path` I receive the lamest error ever: "Move-Item : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes." Seriously? What kind of asinine limitation is that?! Moving on...

`copy-item -destination F:\empty_folders` Apparently I can get around the limitation of move-item by using `copy-item` and then use `remove-item`. No such luck, however. I started the script with `copy-item` first. PowerShell didn't throw any errors, but also didn't do *any* thing else. It just sat there for the better part of an hour. No directories were moved.

**Summary:**
How do I take the list of empty folders that I have and, *using PowerShell*, move those empty directories elsewhere (across volumes!) deleting the originals after the move? Notice the caveat "using PowerShell" as I've already thought about adding RoboCopy to the mix but would like to keep it within PowerShell.

Comment: Are you avoiding `foreach` or `ForEach-Object` intentionally?

Comment: Are you wainting to maintain the same directory structure for the empty folders at the target location?  If so, how will you know if a parent folder in the path was contained any files or not? If eg you get have c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 and folder1 and folder2 contains files, but folder3 and folder4 do not, does folder 3 count as an "empty" folder?

Comment: @jscott I was under the impression that `ForEach-Object` was unnecessary since `Where-Object` fed the next pipe items one at a time.

Comment: @mjolinor I had hoped to maintain directory structure yes. However, the roadblock in this post kept me from thinking that far ahead. Folder 3 would not be considered an empty folder, I suppose. Perhaps it would be better to check for the size of the folder and if it was zero consider it empty?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138849/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pretty frustrated with this as well, but like you said `copy-item` followed by `remove-item` will work:

```
gci e:\file_server | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | ?{$_.GetFiles().count -eq 0} | 
%{copy-item -LiteralPath $_.fullname -Destination f:\path; remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Note this is not just a limitation with `Move-Item` and Powershell but applicable to .Net `System.IO.Directory.Move` and to be fair, the documentation says so:

> Move-Item will move files between drives that are supported by the
>   same provider, but it will move directories only within the same
>   drive.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315310.aspx

PS: You got the `"Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."` error because the `$_.move(F:\path)` that you were trying must be inside a foreach-object like so - `%{$_.move(F:\path)}`

Comment: One side effect of using GetFiles() is that it doesn't count files in the sub-folders.  This may result in folders with files being copied too.  For example c:\test\pstest\empty1\notempty\test.txt. If empty1 has no files in it, it'll show up as matched. I'm not sure if this would be an issue for Wesley.

Comment: @Jon So a folder with a folder in it but no files will return '0' with getfiles()? That would be a problem. Perhaps I need to remake the question since this is getting complicated.

Comment: @WesleyDavid - ask a different question. This one is really about moving from one volume to another.