# Unable to move-item in Powershell to remote file share

Tags: powershell, file-sharing

I have the need to run a Powershell command on a remote computer that will move a file from the remote computer to another computer on the network.

```
PS H:\> invoke-command -computername server1 -scriptblock {move-item c:\jobs\archive\A1051626.zip "
\\FilerServer\jobs\archive\"}
```

This command results in the following error:

> Access to the path is denied.
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\jobs\archive\A1051626.zip:FileInfo) [Move-Item], Unauthorized
>      AccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

If I edit the PS command to copy the file to a local system folder the command runs fine.

The user account that I am running the PS script from on my local computer has permissions to copy files to the remote file server. I have double checked this, and I can mannually copy the files to the file share from Windows Explorer.

What is preventing the copy operation in PowerShell? How can I get this task to run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a double hop issue. You have to use CredSSP to delegate your credentials to the remote computer.

Try the solution mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx

Also, note that Move-Item may not work for moving from filesystem to network share. You might have to use `Copy-Item` and `Remove-Item`

See this answer here: [How do you move files/folders across volumes with Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138849/how-do-you-move-files-folders-across-volumes-with-powershell)