# move-item: access denied on server 2012 only

Tags: powershell, remote-access, access-rights

I am running a PS script that people's personal drives to another location when they are terminated.  Script runs fine when the users drive is on a 2003 or 2008 server, but I get an error when the drive is on a 2012 server. 
"move-item: Acces to the path '[\P drive path]' is denied.

Checked my group's rights to the file servers, and they are the same.  Do not know 2012 well enough to know why this would be bombing out on that server only.  Any ideas?

Comment: please provide the code you are using

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. Are you sure P: drive is what you expect it to be and not another location? Are you trying to overwrite a file that is in use or already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138849/how-do-you-move-files-folders-across-volumes-with-powershell), should have looked deeper.

Seems it cannot be done with move-item. When I said it worked under Server 2008, well, it did, but only because the user profile containers for a certain number of users is on the same file server/drive as where the terminations were being moved to.  The other bunch, were on another file server, so move-item cant be  used.  Copy-item/Remove-item seems to work, just have to work on some error handling.